# Use AVG() and VAR() in the same SQL query?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table here called Supplies:

```
SUPNR (supplies)    PRODNR (supplies)   PURCHASE_PRICE (supplies)   DELIV_PERIOD (supplies)
21                        0119                15.99                        1
21                        0178                55.99                        1
21                        0289                17.99                        1  
21                        0327                56.00                        6
21                        0347                16.00                        2
21                        0384                55.00                        2
```

Assume product number can uniquely define a product and I'm not sure what it means exactly.

So I can easily find the average price per product with the following SQL:

```
SELECT AVG(PURCHASE_PRICE)
FROM supplies
GROUP BY PRODNR
```

This returns perfectly fine (I only posted two rows for space issues):

```
PRODNR (supplies)   AVG(PURCHASE_PRICE) ()

0119                 15.990000
 
0154                 21.500000
```

But what does this direction mean by "variance per product" and how would I do that in one SQL query?

Here's what I tried doing:

```
SELECT AVG(PURCHASE_PRICE), VAR(PRODNR) AS VARIANCE_PER_PRODUCT
FROM supplies
GROUP BY PRODNR
```

But I'm getting this error:

Error: FUNCTION pgdb____1602696043_5f87336bef7ea.VAR does not exist — ERROR CODE 1305

Any ideas? Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`VAR` is not a mysql function.

You should use [variance()](https://www.w3resource.com/mysql/aggregate-functions-and-grouping/aggregate-functions-and-grouping-variance().php)

```
SELECT AVG(PURCHASE_PRICE), VARIANCE(PURCHASE_PRICE) AS VARIANCE_PER_PRODUCT
FROM supplies
GROUP BY PRODNR
```

Answer (score 0):

It would be `variance()` instead of `var()`

```
SELECT AVG(PURCHASE_PRICE), variance(PRODNR) AS VARIANCE_PER_PRODUCT
FROM supplies
GROUP BY PRODNR
```